# Not able to transform my spark dataframe after loading the data from teradata DB using JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, teradata

`SQLException: Query failed (#20240121_161147_26073_n4j2r): Query failed (#20240121_161231_07455_v59u7): [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 7504] [SQLState HY000] in UDF/XSP/UDM SYSLIB.presto_table_operator: SQLSTATE U0002: Starburst: Illegal state: Unsupported Teradata type: 34 Caused by: FailureInfo.FailureException: Query failed (#20240121_161231_07455_v59u7): [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 7504] [SQLState HY000] in UDF/XSP/UDM SYSLIB.presto_table_operator: SQLSTATE U0002: Starburst: Illegal state: Unsupported Teradata type: 34 Caused by: FailureInfo.FailureException: Query failed (#20240121_161231_07455_v59u7): [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 7504] [SQLState HY000] in UDF/XSP/UDM SYSLIB.presto_table_operator: SQLSTATE U0002: Starburst: Illegal state: Unsupported Teradata type: 34 Caused by: FailureInfo.FailureException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 7504] [SQLState HY000] in UDF/XSP/UDM SYSLIB.presto_table_operator: SQLSTATE U0002: Starburst: Illegal state: Unsupported Teradata type: 34`

I did a spark.read and I was able to read the table using JDBC but when I try to transform the dataframe (using display command). I get this exception. When I do a `dataframe.count()` ,I got 539695

My spark version is 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12). Not sure if the problem is with my version or my dataframe is too large. The job was running fine for a very long time.